# WARNING: amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel (on both 16.04 & 18.04)

Tags: 16.04, drivers, kernel, 18.04, dkms

Since last 4 days, I am trying to install amdgpu pro drivers on my ubuntu system and I am getting error.

1. I have downloaded drivers from [here](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Radeon-Software-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx) for Rx580.
2. I am following installation instructions from [here](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx).
3. First-time installation, I am getting dkms command not found.

[image]

4. executing below command will show me to install dkms

   dkms status
5. Installing dkms using below command

   sudo apt-get install dkms
6. Then try to install using below command, and getting error below is the screenshot for the same.

   ./amdgpu-pro-install -y

[image]

7. I have also tried on kernel 4.4 & 4.8 & 4.16 (getting above error on all kernels)

Below is my system configuration

[image]
[Motherboard](https://www.asus.com/in/Motherboards/PRIME-B350-PLUS/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As someone pointed out in the forums (https://community.amd.com/thread/228245) the script is broken.

Provided that you have the right kernel and header version, you need to install the missing packages manually, run:

```
apt install amdgpu-dkms libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1 libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm2-amdgpu
```

Comment: Just to add. This solution doesn't work on kernel 4.18.0-15.

Comment: Luckily the more recent release packages have been fixed

Comment: I get the same error with amdgpu v20.30 on 18.04.4 HWE. Running above install command manually results in: $ sudo apt install amdgpu-dkms libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1 libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm2-amdgpu
libdrm-amdgpu1 is already the newest version (2.4.101-2~18.04.1).
libdrm-amdgpu1 set to manually installed.
amdgpu-dkms is already the newest version (1:5.6.5.24-1109583).
libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1 is already the newest version (1:2.4.100-1109583).
libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1 set to manually installed.
libdrm2-amdgpu is already the newest version (1:2.4.100-1109583).
libdrm2-amdgpu set to manually installed.