# amdgpu-pro install on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: 18.04, dkms, amdgpu-pro

I have Ubuntu 18.04.2 and Graphics card asus rx580 8gb.
Driver installation problem on ubuntu 18.04.2

1. I go on "https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-580"
   for download driver. I have last driver just only "Radeon™ Software for Linux® Driver for Ubuntu 18.04.1".  Ok, I try install.
2. I open terminal and try install this, but I have problem. 
   I run in terminal:

   > $ `sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install`

returns me:

> WARNING: amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel

This dosen't work. Whay I can to force work it?

Comment: The link you provided is not static - it points to an updated driver now, version 19.20. I think it make sense to try the most recent driver package now.

Answer (score 5):

You appear to be affected by [this bug.](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109440)

The DKMS will not compile on the 4.18 Linux kernel in 18.50.

Some workarounds are:

**A)** Wait for the 19.10 driver, which [reportedly will be released](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109440#c2) within the coming months.

**B)** Downgrade to kernel 4.15 which is [reported to work.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/502110/67643) If this didn't work for you install [linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-47-generic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-47-generic) and [linux-headers-4.15.0-47-generic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/linux-headers-4.15.0-47-generic) as well as [linux-image-4.15.0-47-generic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/linux-image-4.15.0-47-generic) and try again.

**C)** Use the no-dkms switch when installing with kernel versions 4.17 or later. `amdgpu-pro-install --no-dkms` Also [reported to work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/501267/how-to-fix-amdgpu-dkms-failed-for-running-kernel-when-installing-amd-gpu-drive#comment945938_502110).

**Note:** I do not have your hardware so I cannot test. This answer is the result of research and nothing more.

Sources:

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109440

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/501267/how-to-fix-amdgpu-dkms-failed-for-running-kernel-when-installing-amd-gpu-drive

If you are getting a `dkms not found` error refer to [this answer.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1041546/225694)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately I could not install this driver. To eliminate errors, I installed a clean system every time before attempting to install amdgpu. Probably, I just have to wait for the new driver. Or me hope for an answer from amd (maybe they will share some instruction with me, and I will definitely share it).

Comment: The `--no-dkms` argument helped in my case, thanks for that one!

Comment: @Marc-AndréAppel I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score -1):

I have had simmilar problems with amdgpu-pro (19.Q4) drivers, but I'm using WX 7100.

```
Note: Customers who have upgraded to the latest 4.15 Kernel for Ubuntu will need to use an 18.20 based driver such as Radeon™ Pro Software Adrenalin Edition 18.Q3 for Linux.
```

I've installed latest 4.14.* mainline kernel and that solved my problem with installation.
Then I've discovered that amdgpu-pro drivers works fine with 5.0.0-37 kernel, but must be installed on previous (4.14.*) kernel. 
After that I've removed old kernel.