# Ubuntu 20.10 Boots Only in recovery Mode

Tags: drivers, graphics, data-recovery, boot-repair, additional-drivers

Ubuntu stuck on the hp starting screen. It's booting in Recovery mode; This problem started when I mistakenly tried to install the Nvidia graphics driver when I had Radeon graphics in laptop.
On running

```
   sudo lshw -c video
```

I get the following

> *-display UNCLAIMED
> description: VGA compatible controller
> product: HD Graphics 620
> vendor: Intel Corporation
> physical id: 2
> bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
> version: 02
> width: 64 bits
> clock: 33MHz
> capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
> configuration: latency=0
> resources: memory:b0000000-b0ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
>
> *-display UNCLAIMED
> description: Display controller
> product: Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile]
> vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
> physical id: 0
> bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
> version: 83
> width: 64 bits
> clock: 33MHz
> capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
> configuration: latency=0
> resources: memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:b1200000-b123ffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1240000-b125ffff

I tried

lsmod | grep amd

It doesn't return anything.
Windows is working fine, so probably not a hardware problem.

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163516/problems-with-booting-the-system/1163539#1163539 to fix the drivers

Comment: Thanks Raffa, I uninstalled nvidia successfully; Auto installing Ubuntu drivers didn't install any new driver. I tried rebooting, still the laptop is struck at the logo scree.

Comment: You probably need to uninstall AMD/ ATI Radeon drivers as well.

Comment: I couldn't find a command to remove ATI Radeon driver in ubuntu;

Comment: Practice common sense and be careful while you see if [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219927/ubuntu-18-doesnt-boot-after-amd-driver-install) helps?